# Using void pointers: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location

Tags: c, void-pointers

I'm just experimenting with void pointers, I wanted to use them on C-type strings.
It seems that this line of code throws the exception, but I don't know why:

```
printf("My name is %s", *((char*)ptr));
```

Here is the entire code:

```
int main()
{
    char prenume[] = "Alexandru";
    char* name = prenume;
    int age = 33;
    float height = 1.81;

    void* ptr;
    ptr = name;
    printf("My name is %s", *((char*)ptr));
    ptr = &age;
    printf("\nAge:%d", *((int*)ptr));
    ptr = &height;
    printf("\nHeight:%2.2f", *((float*)ptr));
    return 0;  
}
```

I am using MS Visual Studio

I would appreciate any answer...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use the `void * ptr` as a general pointer to any data types.
The problem in your code is as below.

```
int main()
{
    char prenume[] = "Alexandru";
    char* name = prenume;
    int age = 33;
    float height = 1.81; //<=== this line will cause a truncation warning at compile time

    void* ptr;
    ptr = name;
    printf("My name is %s", *((char*)ptr)); // <======= this line will cause access violation error at runtime
    ptr = &age;
    printf("\nAge:%d", *((int*)ptr));
    ptr = &height;
    printf("\nHeight:%2.2f", *((float*)ptr));
    return 0;  
}
```

You should use `((char*)ptr)` (remove the leading `*`). This expression resolve to the **address** of the `A`. Because `%s` expects the start address of a string.

If you use `*((char*)ptr)`, it resolves to the **char value** `A`. The ASCII value of `A` is `0x41`, which is not an address you can usually access. And below debug message shows that it is the address `0x41` is causing access violation.

[image]

After making above changes, your code can run like below:

[image]

And btw, C is a dangerous beauty...

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I understand more clearly now.
Yes, I'm only learning C/C++ for now just to have a solid programming base. I know that other languages are more easy to use...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is inconsistent. You're getting the address of `age` and `height` and putting it into `ptr`, but you put `name`'s value directly. Getting the address of  a value adds a level of indirection (as in, using `&` on a `char*` gives you not `char*` but `char**`, the address of an address of a char).

Fixing your code to make it consistent:

```
void* ptr;
ptr = &name; //Added &.
printf("My name is %s", *((char**)ptr));
ptr = &age;
printf("\nAge:%d", *((int*)ptr));
ptr = &height;
printf("\nHeight:%2.2f", *((float*)ptr));
```

And it should now work. You can also rid yourself of that extra level of indirection (`&` and `*`) for less confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've tried it and the debugger throws the same exception.
Adding & only points ptr to the address of pointer name. 

I think it may have to do with the printf function. 
I've tried it like this:

`
void* ptr;
    ptr = name; 
    std::cout << *(char*)ptr;
`

and it works, only it outpus the first character "A" which is normal.

But I want to print the entire name without using pointer incrementation